# kafka replication flushed offset details

Tags: apache-kafka

The kafka replication design wiki(https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Replication) mentions of kafka flushed offset as a separate offset than the HW and LEO. Wiki Comment

```
Data before the flushed offset is guaranteed to be persisted on disks
```

There is no more detailed information available on this offset in the wiki and as well online in other articles. Any details on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, the HW should have no direct relationship with flushed offset. Flushed offset should be the point where no data before it has not been persisted on disks due to Linux's default write-back strategy.

Say a partition commit log has 10 messages in it. HW is now 10 since all these 10 messages are fully replicated. Later the producer deliveries another 5 messages. Now the LEO(log end offset) is at 15, but HW is still 10 since these new-created 5 messages are not fully replicated by all followers. But remember this commit log is still in the pagecache, so due to the default writeback, it's very likely the kernel has not flushed all the messages to disk, so flushed offset might be before or after the HW.

Comment: ok if in the above example if the flushed offset is at 10 and LEO is at 15 and say that the in sync replica has just ack 5 message so the HW has been advanced to 15( and so the client has been acked as well) and then if we loose the leader node then we would still have a replica of message on slave node there by maintaining durability. This sounds correct @amethystic